# Get what CultureInfo threads use in app when no CurrentCulture is set

Tags: c#, .net, localization, globalization

If I create a .NET application here in America, haven't set the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` in my code, then look at the value of `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`, it will be a `CultureInfo("en-US")` object.

But now let's say that in another piece of code does `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("ja-JP")`. So the current thread is Japanese.

Now, in the current Japanese thread, I want to get the value of what that default CultureInfo was *before* it was set to Japanese—*what the thread will use if no code changes the CurrentCulture.*

How can I do this?

I tried `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CultureInfo` but get `InvariantCulture`, which is obviously not `CultureInfo("en-US")`.

Comment: What kind of application is this? You could create a static variable at application startup that captures the default culture, and make that available, through a property, to all other threads?

Comment: CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture What about this property ?

Comment: You could pinvoke GetSystemDefaultLocaleName().  That's of course silly when you can just as easily store the CultureInfo before you change it.